# React ovverride shown component with new component after server response

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-effects

I would want load new component after server response using React. Its could be a simple operation but something does not working at the moment. My code is the following:

```
const formSubmit = async e => {

  e.preventDefault();

  const response = await dataSubmit({
      toSend
  });

  if(response.status === 200){
    console.log("status 200");
     return(
        <>
          <ComponentPage />
        </>
     );
  }
  else{
    console.log("error status");
    return(
       <>
        <ComponentPage  />
       </>
    );
 }
}


async function dataSubmit(toSend) {
  
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(toSend)
    })
      .then(data => (data.json()))

}
```

I tried removing `e.preventDefault()` or using effect but is not working. This component will have to ovverrife atually Form component shown. `console.log` lines works.  How can I solve? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returning a component as part of `formSubmit` or a `clickHandler` won't render the component.

the simplest way i can think of doing is to, make the `render()` or the default return of this component to be conditional.

have a `loading` state, set `true` when the form is submitted and `false` when you get the response. render your `<Component/>` only if `loading` is false.

something like this,

```js
   const YourComponent = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    
    //set loading when form is submitted.
    // unset it when the response is recieved.
    return <>
        {loading} ? <Loader/> : <Component/>
    </>
  }
```

you can extend the same principle to show errors as well.